# Is it possible to access the raw data in Core Data for a Transformable attribute

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have an image field of type transformable and a typical ImageToDataTransformer class. 99% of the time that's perfect and great shortcut, but just occasionally I find myself transforming the managed object back to NSData (knowing that if it wasn't for the ImageToDataTransformer I would have got NSData in the first place).  As these operations are fairly expensive on an iPhone, is there a way of avoiding the transformer on the rare occasions I just want the NSdata ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the transformable attribute, but no transformer. Then, handle the transformation manually.

Comment: What (then) would be the difference between the transformable field and a binary data field holding the NSData directly?

Comment: Not sure. Does it matter? Manually managing the image data will allow you to get that performance gain on those rare occasions.

Comment: Only in so far as I was having issue with image storage as binary. Random crashes but nothing I could figure out. I switched to the transformable and transformers and its been solid. All I really did was change the type, and move my manual transformations into a transformer. Sounds like I have to try going half way back :-)

Comment: Transformables are pretty much not worth the trouble.  Every time I want to deal with unusual data I will write the accessors myself and either store them as something else (JSON for a UIColor for the common example) and png data for an image, etc.  I do not like the Transform attribute as it abstracts a bit too much for my tastes.